# Ошибка в решении задачи " Написать функцию, которая принимает три целых числа и возвращает большее из них, если числа равны, то любое из них"

Tags: php

Решаю задачи по php для начинающих.
Задача :

> Написать функцию, которая принимает три целых числа и возвращает большее из них, если числа равны, то любое из них.

Код:

```php
<?php

/*
Написать функцию, которая принимает три целых числа и возвращает большее из них, если числа равны, то любое из них
*/


function task1(int $a, int $b, int $c) : int
{  if ($a > $b) {
    if ($a > $c) {
        return '$a';
    } else {
        return '$c';
    }
} elseif ($b > $c) {
            return '$b';
    } else {
        return '$c';
} else {
return '$a || $b || $c';
       }
}
$d = task1(5, 10, 35);
echo $d;
```

Ошибку пишет

> ...в строке  } else {
> return '$a || $b || $c';
> }

Прошу помощи у более опытных

Comment: заметьте, в вашей задачи на вход приходит 3 числа,и вернуть надо число, вы же на с какой-то непонятной целью делаете из них строки.

Comment: Спасибо, исправила. Теперь ошибка вылазит ниже(((

Comment: не работает последний блок с else. Если его закомментировать, то конструкция выдает наибольшее. А вот с этим блоком не выдает вариант, если они равны(

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать вот так. Тут по сути не важно сколько у тебя аргументов приходит всегда возвращается максимальное из них

```
function task1(int $a, int $b, int $c) : int
{
return max(func_get_args());
}
```

Ещё вариант с if как вы написали в комментах.

```
function task1(int $a, int $b, int $c) {
    $numbers = [$a,$b,$c];
    $max = $a;
   
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        if ($number > $max) {
            $max = $number;
        }
    }
    
    return $max;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать про такое решение!

Comment: Но, к сожалению, тут необходимо использовать условие if (указано в задании), вот и мучаю эту конструкцию(

Comment: Обновил код, добавил с if и циклом. Может такой вариант подойдёт

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: что по вашему делает `func_num_args()`?

Comment: Судя по всему, возвращает количество аргументов функции?